# Django React project structure

Tags: django, reactjs, git, structure

I have a project with Django as back-end.

And for the client side I have 4 different sections:

- Django Admin Panel for super user which renders by Django itself.
- User **Login** and **Signup** section which is rendered by Django-Jinja template system.
- App admin panel which is a react app
- Main app front-end which is a react app

The structure that I have in my mind is like this:

```
├── djangoproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py (can be folder)
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
|   ├── admin_panel
|   ├── core
|   ├── auth
|   └── ...
├── templates
|   ├── admin_panel (react)
|   ├── core (react)
|   └── auth
├── static
└── manage.py
```

I have two questions:

1- should I change the structure of my project (for example bring react folders outside or use frontend folder naming instead of templates?)

2- Is it common (or reasonable) to use **git sub module** for react apps and only commit build of them in main project? If it is can you give any example or best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the best practices of the project structure, I think you should create a different repository(folder) for front-end(react) outside the back-end repository (folder).

**Backend Structure**

I follow this project structure:

```
├──djangoproject
|
|__config
|  |
|  |__settings
|  |  | 
|  |  |__base.py
|  |  |__local.py
|  |
|  |__urls.py
|  |__wsgi.py
|  |__ __init__.py
|
|__djangoproject
|  |
|  |__users (user app dirctory)
|  |__products (product app dirctory)
|  |__ __init__.py
|
|
|__static
|  |
|  |__css
|  |__js
|
|__media
|
|__manage.py
|__gitignore
```

**Front-End Structure**

```
├──djangoproject(React)
|
|__app
|  |
|  |__assests
|  |  | 
|  |  |__fonts
|  |  |__images
|  |
|  |__components
|  |  |__your components
|  |__containers
|  |  |__Your containers
|  |__app.js
|
|
|__README.md
|
|__package.json
|__gitignore
```

For a better understanding of project structure I recommend you follow the Django cookie cutter (https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for back-end and use react boilerplate (https://www.reactboilerplate.com/) for front-end.

Comment: how do you separate two react apps and where do you store build of react project?